# обработка исключений паскаль

Tags: pascal, исключения, freepascal

Почему ошибка при компиляции? Пишет что неизвестный оператор try

```
program untitled;
uses crt, SysUtils;
var a, b, c: integer;

BEGIN
  try   
    writeln('write a, b,c : ');
    readln(a,b,c);
    if (a>b)and(a>c) then
      write(a, ' is max value')
    else if (b>a)and(b>c) then
      write(b, ' is max value')
    else if(c>a) and(c>b) then
      write(c, ' is max value')
    else
      write('there is not a max value');
  except
    on System.FormatException do
    write('Format error');
  end;
END.
```

Вот такие ошибки

> без имени.pas(5,1) Error: Identifier not found "try"
>   без имени.pas(6,5) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifieWRITELN" found

Comment: Какая ошибка? Предполагаю, что после `write('mistakes');` забыли дописать `end;`

Comment: @Dima нет. он не понимает контрукцию try...except Может нужно библиотеку какую-нибудь подключить?

Comment: Текст ошибки в вопросе приведите полностью плиз

Comment: Добавьте модуль `SysUtils` в раздел `uses`.

Comment: @Dima Все-равно не работает.

Comment: Укажите эту директиву после {$MODE objfpc} после строки `program untitled;`

Comment: @Dima добавил код и ошибки

Comment: @Kromster Добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется здесь намешаны все возможные ответвления `Pascal`

```
program untitled;

{$MODE OBJFPC}  // обязательная директива для поддержки исключений

uses SysUtils;  // обязательный модуль

VAR

BEGIN
  try   

  except on E: EInOutError do

  end;  
END.
```

[Классы исключений](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/index-4.html) для FreePascal

`System.FormatException` - исключение для Pascal.ABC